# Arduino: faster alternatives to digitalread() and digitalwrite()?

Tags: performance, arduino

What are the fastest alternatives to calling the Arduino functions `digitalread()` and `digitalwrite()`?  AVR-specific or chip-specific solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Reading this and your last question, it seems like you want to do something pretty quickly. I think giving details on what it is and how fast might be useful.

Comment: @Oli, good idea, thanks.  Current project is a tuning system for RC transmitters.  It works well, but I would like to make the RC PWM signal decoding efficient so that I can use the same framework for other projects.  Here's a writeup on what I have so far:   http://eastbay-rc.blogspot.com/2011/11/arduino-sketch-for-transmitter-tuning.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Access the digital ports directly!

- http://www.billporter.info/ready-set-oscillate-the-fastest-way-to-change-arduino-pins/

> The 3 methods I tested were
>
> - digitalWrite(pin, LOW);         digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
> - CLR(PORTB, 0) ;     SET(PORTB, 0);
> - PORTB |= _BV(0);                   PORTB &= ~(_BV(0));

[...]

> [image]
>
> As you can see, digitalWrite takes around 56 cycles to complete, while direct Port addressing takes 2 cycles. That’s a big difference in time for programs that have lot’s of IO operations!

Comment: You can use preprocessor macros to translate the pin to port and bit: `*portOutputRegister(digitalPinToPort(pin)) |= digitalPinToBitMask(pin)` // from https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/9f8d27f09f3bbd1da1374b5549a82bda55d45d44/cores/arduino/Arduino.h#L178

Answer (score 7):

This library is a good alternative:
http://code.google.com/p/digitalwritefast/

Answer (score 4):

Folks at Arduino.SE [have already](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/is-the-digitalwritefast-library-still-needed) discussed and tested this. As it turns out, `digitalWriteFast()` is not much of improvement over regular `digitalWrite()`. Direct port access, however, is about 35-40 times faster than `digitalWrite()`.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, access the digital ports directly. But with style!

By writing hard-coded values directly into the hardware registers, you loose in readability and portability.

I've published on Github a tool I called HWA that lets you use an object-oriented interface to the hardware that does not require a C++ compiler and produces high efficiency binary code.

HWA is there: https://github.com/duparq/hwa

Comment: "high efficiency binary code" would sound much more authoritative along with actual measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ChipKit Uno32.](http://digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,892,893&Prod=CHIPKIT-UNO32) It's much faster than the AVR-based Arduinos. It will also deal with your timing problems.

Comment: I don't think buying faster hardware is the best answer here, at least not until you've reached the bounds of your current hardware and decided that you need something faster.

Comment: Why the downvotes? He wanted the *fastest* solution, not just a faster one, which I've provided. Can anyone suggest a faster Arduino-based solution?

Comment: Because the ChipKit is not an arduino, but an arduino compatible platform. This means that although port switching is faster , there is a big likelihood of a rewrite of some libraries. Ethernet, XBee, SD card libraries may not work at all out of the box.
Furthermore, Mark specifically asks for alternative function calls of digitalRead/Write, not for a new platform (doh).

Comment: No, it's a fine answer... I didn't realize such a thing existed, and at such a price point.  Downvoters, follow my lead and upvote... Thanks Leon!

Comment: I said it would  probably solve all Mark's problems.

Comment: Changing hardware is never a good solution. At the very least you miss out on some good learning and will never learn what would be efficient use of the hardware.

Comment: @Rick_2047 I wouldn't say "never" - if the requirement is new or expanded or the quantity increases, it can make sense to look at alternatives.  But I agree that blindly throwing hardware at gross software inefficiencies is unsophisticated - sometimes it doesn't even work as higher performance systems can add overhead of their own and sometimes end up slower than simpler ones for some tasks.  There's really no substitute for learning about the platform you use or contemplate using.

Comment: Upvoted. Reason is that 'Arduino' isn't just the hardware-series, but also the application environment. The Arduino hardware actually has specific names s.a. 'Duemillanove', 'Neo', 'LilyPad', 'Nano', 'NanoPro' etc. Quite often people searching for answers on 'Arduino' are approaching it from a software compatibility (and it's ease) standpoint, which the ChipKit solution does seem address. The icing on the cake seems to be the compatibility with many shields. Like Mark, I wasn't aware of this, and glad I found it here.